# Backbone: fetch and scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Think I been staring at this to long but, I'm trying to bring an object outside the scope of the fetch success method when it completes the fetch.

```
cars.fetch().complete(function(){
    newSuggested = cars.models.filter(function (model) { 
       return _.contains(model.attributes.suggestedTo, storedVin)  
    });
})
console.log(newSuggested) //undefined
```

How can I get the `newSuggested` outside the `fetch` scope after it successfully fetched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have declared `newSuggested` somewhere above in the code, it is a global variable on the window (this is not the problem, just pointing it out).

The reason it is undefined where you are logging it, is because when that `console.log` statement is run, the fetch has not completed.

Whatever you are going to do with `newSuggested`, you need to do it from within the `complete` callback function.

```
// declare the variable using var, so it is not global
var newSuggested;
cars.fetch().complete(function(){
    newSuggested = cars.models.filter(function (model) { 
       return _.contains(model.attributes.suggestedTo, storedVin)  
    });
    console.log(newSuggested); // works!
    // do something with newSuggested here, hard to tell what you are trying to do.
    probablyUpdateViewInSomeWay(newSuggested);
});
// fetch not complete here!
// this is not a scope problem, but an async problem.
// complete callback has not been called yet.
console.log(newSuggested) //undefined, this is expected
```

Side note: `complete` is deprecated in jQuery 1.8, so you should use `done` instead.

Comment: If you are using Backbone you could also use the collection method 'where'. You can then pass the attributes you want to filter out as a hash. The result of the 'where' method is an Array with all the filtered models.

Comment: Ok so I wasnt crazy, im just going to do everything within the scope opposed to trying to bring it out. This helped much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is correct, you can even explicitly use `window.newSuggested` to make the variable global (though is default like this).
You have to move the `console.log` after "complete" as call order in the execution flow

```
cars.fetch().complete(function(){
    window.newSuggested = cars.models.filter(function (model) { 
       return _.contains(model.attributes.suggestedTo, storedVin)  
    });
    global_log();
})

function global_log(){console.log(newSuggested);};
```